# Declaring tables in Slick

Tags: database, scala, static, slick

I've been getting errors when trying to do many-to-many relations in Slick. This [test](https://github.com/slick/slick/commit/01251edbc7f970f29f3a471d7eee27460e6846cf#src/test/scala/scala/slick/test/ql/ForeignKeyTest.scala) shows how to do many-to-many relations in Slick. I followed it but then go this error:

```
 Select(TableNode, "id") found. This is typically caused by an attempt to use a "raw" table object directly in a query without introducing it through a generator
```

I then found out that this is caused by declaring your tables at a static location (an object) and then trying to import it (it works fine if the object is in the same block). http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/lifted-embedding.html#tables

Ok, so `val T = new Table` inside of an `object` is the answer. But now I'm getting this error:

```
recursive method bs needs result type
```

It doesn't need a result type if it is an `object` and not a `val`. I've heard of using a `class` but I can't find any examples on how to do this.

How do you declare many-to-many models and import them from somewhere else?

EDIT:
Here's a gist showing what I mean: https://gist.github.com/pjrt/5332311

If you run the first test, it will pass, no issue.

If you run the second test, the following error is thrown:

```
scala.slick.SlickException: Select(TableNode, "id") found. This is typically caused by an attempt to use a "raw" table object directly in a query without introducing it through a generator.
```

If you run the third test (using vals inside of objects instead of objects directly), you get this error:

```
recursive method bs needs result type
[error]   val A = new Table[(Int, String)]("a") {

recursive value AToB needs type
[error]     def as = AToB.filter(_.bId === id).flatMap(_.aFK)
```

I know why the errors are happening, but I want to know how people got around them. One way is to put the objects inside of a class and instantiating a class every time you want to use Slick (but this seems...weird). Another is to never use Slick-related stuff outside of the package (or at least many-to-many stuff) but that also seems bad.

My question, still is, how do you guys get around this? Is there a proper way?

Comment: Can't you share the code of your table?

Comment: Added a gist to show what I mean.

Comment: If you create a Slick test case and submit a github pull request, we can take a closer. Please place it in https://github.com/slick/slick/tree/master/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests or https://github.com/slick/slick/tree/master/slick-testkit/src/test/scala/scala/slick/test/lifted

Answer (score 0):

The error message you showed makes me think that you defined your tables but tried to access them directly instead of using a for comprehension.

The [test file you were referring](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/01251edbc7f970f29f3a471d7eee27460e6846cf/src/test/scala/scala/slick/test/ql/ForeignKeyTest.scala) has an example right at the bottom, after defining the many-to-many tables that goes like

```
val q1 = for {
  a <- A if a.id >= 2
  b <- a.bs
} yield (a.s, b.s)
q1.foreach(x => println("  "+x))
assertEquals(Set(("b","y"), ("b","z")), q1.list.toSet)
```

What you see is that object table `A` is used as a comprehension generator (i.e. `a <- A`)

Does your code access the tables in some other way?